# Downloading file with input for filename in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

My goal is to make download reactive to change in text field for filename. With the following solution the name of the downloaded file doesn't change from the first filename input.

Example:

```
library("shiny")


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(1, offset=1,
           downloadButton(outputId="save",
                          label="Save")
    ),
    column(2, offset=1,
           textInput(inputId="name",
                     label="Filename:")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  observe({

    data <- data.frame(x=1:50, y=rnorm(50))

    serverDownloadCSV <- function(name, data) {

      dl <- downloadHandler(
        filename=function() {
          if (name == "") {
            paste("Untitled", "csv", sep=".")
          } else {
            paste(name, "csv", sep=".")
          }
        },
        content = function(file) {
          write.table(data, file, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep=",")
        }
      )

      return(dl)
    }

    output$save <- serverDownloadCSV(name=input$name, data=data)

  })
}

runApp(appDir=list(ui=ui, server=server), launch.browser=TRUE)
```

However if I don't have `downloadHandler` as separate function but in the following form:

```
output$save <- downloadHandler(
      filename=function() {
        if (input$name == "") {
          paste("Untitled", "csv", sep=".")
        } else {
          paste(input$name, "csv", sep=".")
        }
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.table(data(), file, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep=",")
      }
    )
```

then it works as intended. What I need to do in order to keep the separate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a call to `input$name` at the beginning of your `observe`. This should do it, althought `append=TRUE` wont work, as it will always create a new file, rather than append to an existing csv-file.

Here is the new `server.R` code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    input$name
    data <- data.frame(x=1:50, y=rnorm(50))

    serverDownloadCSV <- function(name, data) {
      downloadHandler(
        filename=function() {
          if (name == "") {
            paste("Untitled", "csv", sep=".")
          } else {
            paste(name, "csv", sep=".")
          }
        },
        content = function(file) {
          write.table(data, file, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep=",")
        }
      )
    }

    output$save <- serverDownloadCSV(name=input$name, data=data)
  })
}
```

Comment: `append=TRUE` was there only because in my app I first wrote a text line to file before writing the data.